# NullInjectorError: No provider for NbDialogRef! in Nebular Dialog Service

Tags: angular, nebular

I am using **NbDialogService**, and I am opening a component through NbDialogService, on that dialog component I have initialized `Nbdialogref private dialogref: NbDialogRef<AddContactComponent>`. Now I want to also open that component without dialog box, so when I open that I get these error `NullInjectorError: No provider for NbDialogRef!`. Any idea how to open a compoent in dialog box and same component with navigation or routing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using @Optional() in constructor to say the service is not required.

```
constructor(@Optional() private dialogRef: NbDialogRef<any>) {}
```

Note:-
I used this when I used the same component in two places

1. normal component page
2. as a Model page

Answer (score 0):

you need inject in constructor the NbDialogService, not the NgbDialogRef. dialogRef is a simple variable -generally you neen'd use a variable that belongs to the component, just a constant in your function "open"

```
constructor(private dialogService: NbDialogService){}
```

To open a component

```
const dialogref=this.dialogService.open(YourComponent, {
  context: {
    title: 'This is a title passed to the dialog component',
  })
dialogref.onClose.subscribe(name => name && this.names.push(name));
```

Comment: You didn't got my point, Yes I am using the dialogService to open the dialog component, my requirement is to also open that dialog component separately without any dialog box by router.navigate() and as I have initialize dialogref variable in the dialog component it generates this error when I open the same' component with router.navigate()

Comment: sorry, really I din't understand you.I think that you can use @Optional in constructor https://angular.io/api/core/Optional, e.g. `constructor(@Optional() private dialogRef: NbDialogRef<any>) {}` But Really I don't know what it's the reason to inject the NbDialogRef. You can also pass data in state object and depending the data make one or another action, see https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb

Comment: Yeah that worked! Thanks man.. You can also edit or give new answer so I can upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same problem it was that I was using the component *without* invoking it as a Dialog. That is why @Optional works.