# I can't use the NbWindowRef class to close the window Nebular

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular

R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NbWindowRef -> NbWindowRef -> NbWindowRef])

```
app.modules.ts 
NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
NbWindowModule.forChild(),
```

the documentation is a bit flawed I couldn't progress....

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please include full details of the problem so that others can reproduce it themselves. Have a look at the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: I got the same error. This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446045/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-nbdialogref-in-nebular-dialog-service